# Javascript considitional ternary operator not resolving correctly

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Why does this resolve as false:

```
var check = true;
var val = 'bottom-left';

( val !== 'top-left' || val !== 'top-right'  || val !== 'middle-left'  || val !== 'middle-right'  || val !== 'middle'  || val !== 'bottom-left'  || val !== "bottom-right" ) ? check = false : check = true;

alert('check: '+check);
```

Is it because I am testing val more than once? This DOES work:

```
var check = true;
var val = 'bottom-left';

( val !== "bottom-left" ) ? check = false : check = true;

alert('check: '+check);
```

**EDIT:**

Writing it slightly differently DOES work:

```
( val === 'top-left' || val === 'top-right'  || val === 'middle-left'  || val === 'middle-right'  || val === 'middle'  || val === 'bottom-left'  || val === "bottom-right" ) ? check = true : check = false;
```

But I still don't quite understand the difference. Either should resolve correctly right?

**EDIT 2:**

JSFiddle: [resolves false](https://jsfiddle.net/a603zqoL/)

Comment: Something is wrong with your logic because the expression in parens will always be true since `val` will always be `!==` to at least one of those values since it can only have one value.  So, as constructed, it's a non-sensible comparison.

Comment: You should use an array rather then having a massive list of tests against the same value. https://jsfiddle.net/a603zqoL/1/

Comment: @Quentin. Very true.

Answer (score 0):

`||` evaluates as the left hand side if the left hand side is true, otherwise it evaluates as the right hand side.

```
val !== 'top-left' || val !== 'top-right' || etc
```

If `val` is not `'top-left'`, then the left hand side is true. So the condition is true.

Otherwise `val` **is** `'top-left'` in which case it is not `'top-right'`, so the condition is also true.

It never gets beyond the second one and the condition will always be true.

Comment: @user2074704 — When I say "the expression" I mean the expression that is used as the condition for the ternary operation (i.e. the part before the ?)

Comment: I agree the logic isn't quite right, and `(val === 'top-left' || val === 'top-right' etc)` is a better approach. I'm just surprised at the result. In plain english I thought the expression basically read: `if val isn't any of these then set check to false`. But the val does match so it should set check to true.

Comment: It doesn't mean that though. Even if you read it out in plain English it doesn't say that: If val is not top left OR if val is not top right. (Not that you would ever say that in plain english because it doesn't make sense, if is top left then of course it isn't top right)